# Verify that an SSH command has not been embedded in a certificate?

Tags: security, ssh, openssl, ssh-keygen

From `man 8 sshd` with regards to the Authorized Keys File Format and the `command="command"` option:

> Note that this command may be superseded by either an sshd_config(5) ForceCommand directive or a command embedded in a certificate.

Using `ssh-keygen -O force-command="command"` allows a command to be embedded in a certificate.  But how does one verify that a command has **not** been embedded in a certificate?  Along these same lines of preventing unexpected commands from being executed, does `ForceCommand` always override a command embedded in a certificate?

[Can a malicious user bypass a ssh authorized_keys forced command?](https://serverfault.com/questions/162467/can-a-malicious-user-bypass-a-ssh-authorized-keys-forced-command) asks a more general question about security but currently the answers there do not mention commands embedded in certificates.

Comment: Which version of ssh/sshd etc is this ?

Comment: `OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012` and
`OpenSSH_6.2p2 Debian-6~bpo70+1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`

Comment: And if I understand properly, `ssh-keygen -L` is for certificates but not for RSA keys.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -lf` shows a fingerprint but not embedded commands.

Comment: `openssl rsa -in file -text -noout` shows modulus and exponents but not embedded commands.

Comment: `openssl x509 -in file -text -noout` is for certificates and not for RSA keys.

Comment: You may have to generate a cert from the key to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The ssh-keygen man page says

> -O option
>
> ```
>         Specify a certificate option when signing a key.
> ```

The `-O force-command=command` option relates to certificates not keys.

You will need to generate a certificate by signing a key, then you should be able to decode the certificate and see the embedded command.